# Installing latest version of R on Ubuntu 12?

Tags: r, ubuntu, statistics, rstudio

I am having trouble with R installation on my Ubuntu machine. Whenever I try to install a package, it gives me the error:

`package ‘xyz’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)`.

I tried installing R through terminal itself, but I am not able to upgrade.
Is there a way, I can come over this version dependency while installing packages?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you install the most recent R version?

Comment: Yes, definitely update R to most recent version. Also be aware that the error you report occurs if you have a typo or capitalization error in the package name.

Answer (score 3):

To get the most recent version, you need to add CRAN to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, see [instructions on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/). Make sure to pick the address with the right version of Ubuntu (i.e the one installed on your machine, "precise" in my case), otherwise you will have version conflicts.

The thing is that the Ubuntu repository doesn't have the most recent version of R.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Software Center has updated the R install package to the latest version (3.2.2) so  you can easily install R through it.

Just open Ubuntu Software Center and type: r-base

Comment: It's about bloody time they did that

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you talking about?

Comment: That's good news but installing R from CRAN guarantees you that you always get the latest version whereas with Ubuntu repo there will always be a delay : they will never commit themselves to updating R version as soon as it apperas on CRAN.